# Geração do .IPA sem neccesidade de certificado?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple

Bom dia, 
Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de gerar o .IPA ios sem a necessidade de certificado ou algo do tipo para teste em desenvolvimento, para assim não precisar atribuir o dispositivo, há essa possibilidade?

Answer (score 1):

Para testes de **desenvolvimento** (não AdHoc):

- Compile o projeto (<kbd>⌘ + B</kbd>);
- Na barra esquerda do Xcode procure pelo `.app` (pasta `Product`);
- Clique com botão direito e selecione `Show in Finder`;
- Crie uma pasta chamada `Payload` e copie seu `.app` para ela;
- Clique com botão direito na pasta e selecione `Comprimir`;
- Renomeie e troque a extensão de `.zip` para `.ipa`;